# How to return multiple related items per row in a MySQL JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an `articles` table and a `tags` table. The tags table contains tags assigned to the articles. It looks like this:

```
id | article_id | tag_name
---------------------------------

1  | 345        | cats
2  | 345        | dogs
```

My query to fetch the articles (and all tags assigned to each article) looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `articles` a
JOIN `tags` t ON t.article_id = a.id
```

Problem is, this only returns 1 tag, if more than 1 are assigned to a particular article those are not returned. Is there a way I can get all tags associated with an article using a JOIN or is this not possible without a second query?

Comment: [Your query returns every `(article, tag)` pair, as separate records](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8f42/1/0).

Comment: i'm trying your query and it works 
SELECT a.*, t.* ...

Comment: @JakeRow123 your query should return all tags, but they are returned in separate rows.  There is no reason why your query has written will not return two rows for article 345, one row with cats and one row with dogs.  If you are not seeing that then please let us know what you _are_ seeing.  Also, do you want to see a list of tags per article in your result?  What is it you _want_ to see?

Comment: @JakeRow123 Did one of the answers help you? Would you mind giving a checkmark?

Answer (score 0):

If you are after a many-to-many relationship I'd suggest you split your data model into `Article`, `Tag` and `ArticleTag` with `ArticleTag` holding the relation.

The `ArticleTag` table might have columns for `ArticleId` and `TagId`. Then you have your Articles and Tags in separate tables.

Comment: this would be better... didn't +1 because it doesn't actually answer the OP question.

Comment: Might help the OP rethink his data model. ;)

Comment: It's 3NF either way. Only benefit of a separate tag table would be if tags are limited to a specific set.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get all tags associated with an article you simply need

```
select * from tags where article_id = ?
```

If you need the article data as well, you will get a *denormalized* result if you do the join:

```
select a.*, t.tag_name
from articles a
join tags t
on t.article_id = a.id
```

Creating a list of tag names per article is possible only if you turn the names into strings and concatenate them, or let your application fiddle with this kind of stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Though you have not mentioned both the table fully, but I think you need to join on a.article_id = t.article_id